# get ID of current inserted ID

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, database

When you go to my website, i have a homepage with a button: Start enquete.
When you click that button, you will see the enquete.

In the meantime, when you clicked that button. A ID has been inserted in the database.

Index.php:

```
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="x">
            <input type="submit" value="Go to enquete">
        </form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['x'])){
        $test = $database->insert_user_id();
        //header('Location: enquete/page1.php');
    }
```

And the function:

```
function insert_user_id(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (user_id) VALUES (DEFAULT)";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();
        return $this->pdo->('user_id');
}
```

***the return $this->pdo->('user_id'); is something i'm testing with!***
Now my question is. How do i return the last inserted id from the table user.
 I need to show it on the next page. (See //header).

I can't do this with a other query like: `SELECT MAX ID` or `GetLastInsertId`.
This becuase, when some one else also starts the enquete, he will have an other id all of the sudden.

How do i let the person keep the correct id.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

$this->pdo->lastInsertId();

Comment: I can't do this with a other query like: SELECT MAX ID or LastInsertId.
This becuase, when some one else also starts the enquete, he will have an other id all of the sudden.

Comment: @Mitch So, you can get an id of somebody else, who was inserted? Maybe, you can start a transaction?

Comment: When i start the enquete. I want to keep the same ID for the whole enquete time. but if ur halfway, and someone else makes it aswell. ur ID gets changed while ur halfway. Soo i need to keep the id i inserted for the whole time

Comment: @Mitch I think, that locking a table for writing while you are inserting your record and fetching last insert ID, is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Manual [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("...");
$stmt->execute();
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: I can't do this with a other query like: SELECT MAX ID or LastInsertId.
This becuase, when some one else also starts the enquete, he will have an other id all of the sudden.

Comment: what is the problem if new id is beeing inserted ?

Comment: The user_id does not exist. but when you click: Start Enquete. A query will insert a ID in the database. for example 1. I want this ID to be with my the whole time untill the end of the enquete. But if ur halfway, and someone else also starts the enquete. a new ID will be added aswell. with the number 2. And if i use SELECT MAX or LastInsert, i will get the id number 2. while i had the id number 1.

Comment: You can insert the user_id and fetch the lastInsertId right after. Should be fine. It will return the last id inserted over the current connection. So as long as you are not persisting connections between requests? it should be fine.

Comment: you should lock the table untill the last equate has been done, if you lock the table it won't allow you insert a new record in this table so your equate will not be distrubed

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by a Get method.

But you can also do this by slightly adjusting your code.

```
<form method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="x">
        <input type="submit" value="Go to enquete">
    </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['x'])){
    $id = $_POST['X'];
    $test = $database->insert_user_id($id);
    //header('Location: enquete/page1.php');
}
```

and change ur function to

```
function insert_user_id($id){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (user_id) VALUES ('".$id. "')";
    $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    return $this->pdo->('user_id');
}
```

Edit: i failed.

Check this link out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want the id of the row you just inserted into the database, and redirect the user to that one?

Index.php

```
if(isset($_POST['x'])){
    $enqueteId = $database->insert_user_id();
    header('Location: enquete/page1.php?id=' . $enqueteId);
}
```

Function:

```
function insert_user_id(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (user_id) VALUES (DEFAULT)";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();
        return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of PHP mysqli_insert_id() Function which returns the last inserted id of table

For more info go through the link below

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp